# Setting an environment variable in csh

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, csh

I have the following line at the first line in my script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

So I'm using csh.(?)

I wanto assign the output of the following to an environment variable:

```
echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}'
```

I try:

```
set $MYVAR = echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}'
```

But it doesn't work,
How can I do it? I want to do it in a sh file.

Comment: no, /bin/sh is bourne shell or sometimes replaced by bash

Comment: I'm curious, did you mean for your script to be `sh` or `csh`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should look like

```
 #!/bin/csh

 set MYVAR = `echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}'`

 echo $MYVAR
```

I don't have a way to test this right now, let me now if it doesn't work.

---

If you've inherited the basis of your script from someone else, with the `#!/bin/sh`,
 then you have to find out if /bin/sh is really the bourne shell, or if it is a link to /bin/bash

You can tell that by doing

```
   ls -l /bin/sh /bin/bash
```

if you get back information on files where the size is exactly the same, the you're really using bash, but called as /bin/sh

So try these 2 solutions

```
   MYVAR=$(echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}')
   echo $MYVAR
```

AND

```
   MYVAR=``echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}``  
   echo $MYVAR

   # arg!! only one pair of enclosing back-ticks needed, 
   # can't find the secret escape codes to make this look exactly right.
```

in all cases (csh) included, the back-ticks AND the `$( ... )` are known as command substitution.
What every output comes from running the command inside, is substituted into the command line AND then the whole command is executed.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I get this:  sh-3.1$ ls -l /bin/sh /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 785856 Jul 12  2006 /bin/bash
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Jun 15  2010 /bin/sh -> bash  Do I use bash? should I export MYVAR in the end? Thanks

Comment: yes, your /bin/sh and /bin/bash are really the same program. In some systems, using /bin/sh limits the features available in /bin/bash to those in Bourne shell (/bin/sh on older Unix systems like Solaris/HP/AIX, et.al). If you are doing this for yourself, you definitely want to use bash going forward. If you're doing it for a job, you have to find out if it is OK to do so.

Comment: ...... You only need to export variables that are required for use inside a sub-shell environment. You can either test if you program works without the export OR you can just go ahead and export it. That being said, I don't recommend exporting every variable, as that increases memory usage for no real good purpose.

Comment: I tried MYVAR = $(echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,21)}')
export MYVAR  but it doesnt display anythin when I do echo $MYVAR in the application xterm, what went wrong?

Comment: what is in your var $MYUSR ? ALSO no spaces allowed around '=', is that a typo or did you actually run with spaces around '='? AND, I'm assuming that you really had a `export MYVAR` on a separate line? If not, you should use `MYVAR=$(echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,21)}') ; export MYVAR` (note the semicolon). Good luck.

Comment: yes I had spaces around `=`. I removed them. I also added `export MYUSR` in the next line. I added another line `echo "$MYUSR"` it displays the output of MYUSR, when the script is run. But after the application starts I don't see anything when I do `echo "$MYUSR"` in apllication's xterm. I guess it doesn't set the MYUSR env variable.

Comment: if your doing all this setup stuff before you call xterm, I think that is the problem. You're getting a new login shell, that won't inherit the exported environment. You should be using the .bashrc etc to set your variables. There may be a way to start an xterm that isn't a login shell and would inherit the exported env. Sorry, but I feel like we're going down an endless tunnel here. I won't have time to walk you through all of this. Is there a local guru you can ask to take a look at it to confirm this theory? Should only take 10 seconds. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I will ask an expert here, but thank you very much, the code you provided worked, now I know how to set env variable, regards

Comment: In csh, the `set` command does not set an environment variable; it sets a shell variable (which is not inherited by child processes). In sh, use `export` to set an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

if it's `/bin/sh` it's bourne shell or bash, and use back quotes to execute something and this to assign that...

```
MYVAR=`echo $MYUSR | awk ...`
```

Comment: when I do `echo $SHELL` I get `/bin/csh`. When I do `MYVAR = `echo $CARMUSR | awk '{print substr($0,21)}'`` I get "command not found" error.

Comment: your command-line shell might be csh, but the script you're writing, if it has /bin/sh after the #!, will run in bourne shell or bash.

Answer (score 0):

That script first line indicates that it should be interpreted by the Bourne shell (sh), not csh.  Change it to

```
#!/bin/csh
```

Comment: Oops, the initial hash mark didn't make it through the html.  The change is substitute csh for sh.

Comment: In the future, use 4 spaces in front  of code samples, then the '#' looses its meaning (inside S.O.) to make the text bold. Also note at top of text input box, there are a series of editing tools, including {} to auto-indent (With 4 spaces) a block of text, so it will be presented as-is, i.e. for code samples, program output, etc. Good luck and keep posting.

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your code shows clearly you are not using a `csh`. You are using a plain `sh` environment/shell. You have 2 options:

1. Either change the first line to `#!/bin/csh` OR
2. Keeping first line unchanged, update the code for setting the variable.

   ```
   MYVAR=`echo $MYUSR | awk '{print substr($0,4)}`
   echo $MYVAR
   ```

Let me know, if you get any error.