# Cannot find OpenMP environment variables

Tags: openmp

I have a question concerning OpenMP environment variables: When I tried to look for them with, for example:

```
    echo $OMP_NUM_THREADS
```

the variable does not exist. I also try to search for all variables starting with OMP_ through:

```
    env | grep OMP
```

again, there are none of OpenMP environment variables.If I understand correctly, OpenMP is integrated with gnu compiler and intel compiler (I have both gcc and ifort). What should I do to activate these OpenMP environment variables ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in Linux using Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234742/setting-environment-variables-in-linux-using-bash)

Comment: You set them as any other environment variable. There is no point repeating how that can be done here. The details depends on your shell and are described in the respective questions. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739516/setting-an-environment-variable-in-csh https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368944/what-is-the-difference-between-env-setenv-export-and-when-to-use )